# Do I need to register as self-employed or Freiberufler in Germany if I want to sell on Gumroad and such?

Tags: germany, freelance

I am a designer/illustrator/artist and I am soon moving to Germany (from another EU member state). I was hoping to sell my artworks and digital goods on Gumroad/Lemon Squeezy/Figma community etc. as a hobbyist. But first I wanted to test and see what sells and for that I was hoping to put some small digital goods on Gumroad for €0,00+ (pay what you want). Once I understand the market, I may sell for predefined price (although I am not sure how much sells I can make given I have almost no social followers or marketing skills). My question is:

**Do I have to register as a self-employed person before testing the water?**

If my product costs €0,00 and people still pays (On Gumroad or BuyMeACoffee), will it not be considered donation? Are those subjected to taxes as well?